# How to remove timestamps after converting dates (of string type) from 2 distinct CultureInfo

Tags: c#, date, parsing, datetime

I am trying to convert `dates` held in a `CSV` file, from `FR` to `US` formats using:

```
CultureInfo fr = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

string datefr = "25/04/2016";
string dateus= DateTime.Parse(datefr, fr).ToString(us);
```

However I'd like to remove the `timestamp` on `dateus` since it appears as `4/25/2016 12:00:00 AM`

I've attempted to use the `DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)`, by specifying in the 2nd `argument` (of `string` type) the desired format (`MM/dd/yyyy`). But an `exception` is triggered once the `date format` of the data read does not match the specified `CultureInfo` making the conversion an auckward task.

Thus, any idea would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code generates this `4/25/2016 12:00:00 AM` string, that means you *already* parsed your string successfully. That's why this is a formatting issue, not a parsing one.

You need to use custom format on your `ToString` method like;

```
string dateus = DateTime.Parse(datefr, fr).ToString("M/dd/yyyy", us); // 4/25/2016
```

Without any format information, [`Datetime.ToString(IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload uses [The `"G"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) and this generates a string which combination of [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern) properties of your `us` culture.

Comment: @Many thanks, and particularly for the explanation provided - `Soner`.